# how do i make my bot send random generated messages after some time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

Ive been trying to make my bot send random messages after some time.  Here is the code that i tryed

```
    randommessage = bot.SendMessage
    randommessage({
                        to: channelID,
        message: "I like turtles!"
    wait (10)});
    
    randommessage({
                        to: channelID,
        message: "I like ponies!"
});
```

but to no avail it didnt work. I tried asking in a discord server but no one knew how to do it. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Are you using discord.js?

Comment: im using node.js

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a DiscordJS error, but instead a syntax error. The variable `randommessage` contains the function from `bot.SendMessage` without the value of `bot`. This is just how JavaScript works. This means that when you call `randommessage`, the function within it will have no instance of `bot` bound to it. In your error messages, you might see something regarding a value being undefined.

It is a simple fix for this error:

```js
randommessage = bot.SendMessage.bind(bot)
```

When written this way, now the `randommessage` function has an instance of `bot` bound to it and can be executed successfully